# Invalid document reference

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(model.id).setData(["owningRoom" : newRoom])
```

I'm calling this in Swift 4 with Firestore. I want to set the data of a document in collection "users". It gives me the following error:

```
Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1
```

How come? I call the collection first, then the document, hence 2 segments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My bad. The variable model.id was empty, that's why it only had 1 segment.

Comment: This indicates a bug in the validation logic. I've filed a bug so that this error will be clearer.

Comment: This is still the case as I have witnessed today so nothing has been done in a year to address this wrong error message.